# Finding index of an element in a List<FieldInfo> where FieldInfo represents a List<T>

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a custom list class `List<T>` from which I am creating later several lists of objects `List<TypeA> MyList1, MyList2,...`, `List<TypeB> MyList3,...` which are not instantiated at compile time. At runtime I use reflection to instantiate those lists and get their name and save it to a property (why, doesn't matter right now and I am here showing only the affected code):

```
List<FieldInfo> ListOfFields = new List<FieldInfo>();

foreach (FieldInfo field in this.GetType().GetFields())
{
   ListOfFields.Add(field); // saves all my List<T> in the ListOfFields list
}
```

This procedure is a must due to several program constraints. By reflection using the `FieldInfo` field i can get that certain field of a type `List<T>` is, but i need to iterate over their elements to check if a given `<T> obj` (unknown) belongs to one or an other list...
Every `field` of the `foreach` loop will be of the same type `List<T>`.
I am trying to find out a method where to pass a `<T> obj>` and loop through every `field` (`List<T>`) untill I find the match `obj == field[i]`, something like for example:

```
public Tuple<string, string> GetElementTupleFor<T>(T obj)
{
    foreach(FieldInfo field in ListOfFields)
    {
       var elements = field.MyRequestForA_GetElements_Method(); // does such method exist?
       for(int i=0; i<elements.Count; i++)
       {
          if (obj == elements[i])
          {
             return new Tuple<string, string>(field.Name, ""+i);
          }
       }
    }
    return new Tuple<string, string>("NotFound", "?");
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What about `field.GetValue(myObj)`?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on this? It is not yet clear to me how can I check `if(obj == field.GetValue(myObj)`; what would your `myObj` here be?  Please note that here `field` represents a `List<T>`

Comment: `field` does not represent a `List<T>` but a field in `this.GetType()` of type `List<T>`. I think you want to get the value of this field, yes? Then you need to specify the object (myObj) from which the value shall be read.

Comment: Could you please stop tagging these question with `wpf`? There is nothing about WPF here.

Comment: I have the impression that there is some misunderstanding about what a FieldInfo is. It is pure meta-info about the definition of a field in a class, i.e. its name, type, access attributes etc. It does **not** contain the field value - the value is stored in the object (instance) of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Is the list ever going to have objects removed, or the order changed?

If not, why not change from a `List<FieldInfo>` objects to a list of your own wrapper class, that takes the `FieldInfo` and `index` values when an element is added to the list. Your add method becomes:

```
List<MyWrapper> ListOfFields = new List<MyWrapper>();

foreach (FieldInfo field in this.GetType().GetFields())
{
   var myItem = new MyWrapper(field, ListOfFields.Count);
   ListOfFields.Add(myItem);
}

class MyWrapper
{
    public FieldInfo Field { get; private set; }
    public int Index { get; private set; }

    public MyWrapper(FieldInfo field, int index)
    {
        Field = field;
        Index = index;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunatelly I still need to access the elements of the `List<T>` returned into `FieldInfo field`...

Answer (score 0):

If the field is not static, you will have to provide the object from which the field shall be read. Your GetElementTupleFor method thus need one more parameter:

```
public Tuple<string, string> GetElementTupleFor<T>(object objToQuery, T obj)
{
    foreach(FieldInfo field in ListOfFields)
    {
       var elements = field.GetValue(objToQuery) as List<T>;
       if (elements != null)
       {
          for(int i=0; i<elements.Count; i++)
          {
             if (obj == elements[i])
             {
                return new Tuple<string, string>(field.Name, ""+i);
             }
          }
       }
    }
    return new Tuple<string, string>("NotFound", "?");
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, but unfortunatelly i am not able to pass the name of the `objToQuery` due to some architecture constraints...

Comment: I don't get the requirements then. You want to search for a value in several lists which are fields of a class. But *of which object of this class*?

Comment: I have a custom list class `List<T>` from which I am creating later several lists of objects `List<TypeA> MyList1, MyList2,...`, `List<TypeB> MyList3,...` which are not instantiated at compile time.
At runtime I use reflection to instantiate those lists and get their name and save it to a property. This procedure is a must due to several program constraints.
By reflection using the `FieldInfo field` i can get that certain field of a type `List<T>` is, but i need to iterate over their elements to check if a given `<T> obj` (unknown) belongs to one or an other list...

Comment: "and save it to a property": can you show this code?